# Freeing node renders its value to 0. How to delete it completely?

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a **singly linked list**. Just created a function to delete the last node in the list, yet for some reason, it converts the value of the node to `0` but it doesn't completely delete it.

**The function itself:**

```
void deleteNodeEnd(node_t **head) {
    node_t *current = *head;

    while(current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    free(current);
}
```

**How I call it:**

```
deleteNodeEnd(&head);
```

I've earlier added 3 nodes with values `{10, 1, 2}` to the list, and here's what I get after calling `deleteNodeEnd(&head)` and then printing out the list:

```
$ ./linkedlist
10
1
0
```

So eventually my intention was to remove the node with value `2` completely, whereas it just turns into a `0`. Could you please give me a hint where I might be making the mistake?

Comment: You probably want to terminate your list with a NULL after you remove the last element, no?

Comment: Actually no, I've made a mistake in the code while adding it here, then edited it afterwards. Maybe you saw the initial version?

Comment: I saw both versions. My comment still stands. When you free the pointer, accessing it turns into undefined behavior, hence you're seeing a 0. That 0 is not to be relied on.

Comment: Your comment helped a lot, and with the answer below, I totally got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the second last element point to `null` so that it becomes the last element.
You also need to handle if you are deleting the only element from list.

```
void deleteNodeEnd(node_t **head) 
{
    node_t *current = *head;
    if(current->next == NULL)
    {
        *head = NULL;
        free(current);
        return;
    }
    while(current->next->next != NULL) 
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

    free(current->next);
    current->next = NULL;
}
```